# Can't kill my python code. What's wrong?

Tags: python, try-catch, keyboardinterrupt

Okay, so I'm writing a very simplistic password cracker in python that brute forces a password with alphanumeric characters. Currently this code only supports 1 character passwords and a password file with a md5 hashed password inside. It will eventually include the option to specify your own character limits (how many characters the cracker tries until it fails). Right now I cannot kill this code when I want it to die. I have included a try and except snippit, however it's not working. What did I do wrong?

Code: http://pastebin.com/MkJGmmDU

```
import linecache, hashlib

alphaNumeric = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

class main:
    def checker():
            try:
                    while 1:
                            if hashlib.md5(alphaNumeric[num1]) == passwordHash:
                                    print "Success! Your password is: " + str(alphaNumeric[num1])
                                    break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print "Keyboard Interrupt."

    global num1, passwordHash, fileToCrack, numOfChars
    print "What file do you want to crack?"
    fileToCrack = raw_input("> ")
    print "How many characters do you want to try?"
    numOfChars = raw_input("> ")
    print "Scanning file..."
    passwordHash = linecache.getline(fileToCrack, 1)[0:32]
    num1 = 0

    checker()

main
```

Comment: Works for me. =/ I ran your code, and when I tried to kill it (with command-C) it printed "Keyboard interrupt." and quit properly.

Comment: Unrelatedly: Using classes as namespaces the way you have works, but is considered bad style. The `main` on the last line has no effect (the code inside the class but not in a method is run when the class is first evaluated/imported). You have integers in your list of characters, which probably won't work properly; `import string` and you can just use  `string.ascii_letters` + `string.digits` instead.

Comment: do you ever change the value of `num1`?

Answer (score 1):

The way to allow a `KeyboardInterrupt` to end your program is to **do nothing**. They work by depending on nothing catching them in an `except` block; when an exception bubbles all the way out of a program (or thread), it terminates.

What you have done is to trap the `KeyboardInterrupt`s and handle them by printing a message and then continuing.

As for why the program gets stuck, there is nothing that ever causes `num1` to change, so the md5 calculation is the same calculation every time. If you wanted to iterate over the symbols in `alphaNumeric`, then do that: `for symbol in alphaNumeric: # do something with 'symbol'`.

Of course, that will still only consider every possible one-character password. You're going to have to try harder than that... :)

I think you're also confused about the use of classes. Python **does not** require you to wrap everything inside a class. The `main` at the end of your program does nothing useful; your code runs because it is evaluated when the compiler tries to figure out what a `main` class is. This is an abuse of syntax. What you want to do is put this code in a main **function**, and **call** the function (the same way you call `checker` currently).

Comment: He isn't continuing, and there's nothing wrong with trapping a `KeyboardInterrupt`; it's a much nicer user experience to print your own message than to throw a stack trace at them.

Comment: Argh; I missed that the try/catch is outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Besides printing, you need to actually exit your program when capturin `KeyboardInterrupt`, you're only printing a message.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

```
import sys

try:
    ....code that hangs....

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "interupt" 
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use that `try` and `except` block, the error is raised when that error occurs. In your case, `KeyboardInterrupt` is your error here. But when `KeyboardInterrupt` is activated, nothing happens. This due to having nothing in the `except` part. You could do this after importing `sys`:

```
try:
    #Your code#
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Put Text Here'
    sys.exit()
```

`sys.exit()` is an easy way to safely exit the program. This can be used for making programs with passwords to end the program if the password is wrong or something like that. That should fix the `except` part. Now to the `try` part:

If you have `break` as the end of the `try` part, nothing is going to happen. Why? Because `break` only works on loops, most people tend to do it for `while` loops. Let's make some examples. Here's one:

```
while 1:
    print 'djfgerj'
    break
```

The `break` statement will stop and end the loop immediately unlike its brother `continue`, which continues the loop. That's just extra information. Now if you have `break` in a something like this:

```
if liners == 0:
    break
```

That's going to depend where that `if` statement is. If it is in a loop, it is going to stop the loop. If not, nothing is going to happen. I am assuming you made an attempt to exit the *function* which didn't work. It looks like the program should end, so use `sys.exit()` like I showed you above. Also, you should group that last piece of code (in the class) into a seperate function. I hope this helps you!